# How can I sort a table by two columns with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have a html table that is made as follows:

```
<table border="1" id="table">

<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Day</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>21</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>7</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>9</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to use jquery to sort the table so they will appear in the correct Month / Day order. ie:

```
February 4
February 7
February 21
March 1
March 9
```

I've got an array of months:
`var months = ['','January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];`

and I've tried ordering the table using:

```
// Order by Month
var $table=$('#table');
var rows = $table.find('tr').get();
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA = $.inArray( $(a).find('td:eq(0)').text(), months)
    var keyB = $.inArray( $(b).find('td:eq(0)').text(), months);
    if ( keyA.length < 2 ) keyA = "0" + keyA
    if ( keyB.length < 2 ) keyB = "0" + keyB
    console.log ( keyA + ' ' + keyB )
    
    if (!keyA || !keyB) return -1;
    if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
    if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
    return 0;
});

// order by day
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA = $(a).find('td:eq(1)').text();
    var keyB = $(b).find('td:eq(1)').text();
    if ( keyA.length < 2 ) keyA = "0" + keyA
    if ( keyB.length < 2 ) keyB = "0" + keyB
    console.log ( keyA + ' ' + keyB )
    
    if (!keyA || !keyB) return -1;
    if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
    if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
    return 0;
});

$.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $table.children('tbody').append(row);
})
```

But that hasn't worked. I get:

```
March 1
February 4
February 7
March 9
February 21
```

How do I get this to order them correctly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort by two columns you need to separate the sort logic, and call it per column. If the sort logic on the primary column determines that the values are the same, then sort the entities by the secondary column. Try this:

```js
let months = ['', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
let monthSort = (a, b) => Math.min(1, Math.max(-1, months.indexOf(a) - months.indexOf(b)));
let intSort = (a, b) => Math.min(1, Math.max(-1, a - b));

let $table = $('#table');
$table.find('tbody tr').sort((a, b) => {
  let diff = monthSort(a.cells[0].textContent.trim(), b.cells[0].textContent.trim());
  return diff !== 0 ? diff : intSort(parseInt(a.cells[1].textContent, 10), parseInt(b.cells[1].textContent, 10));
}).appendTo($table);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Day</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this before the edit and it worked fine in my page, after the edit the order appears to be wrong.

Comment: I updated the names of the functions and the data passed to them so it's a better separation of concerns. Try copying the whole thing again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in a single sort operation if you translate each `tr` into a `date` object:

```js
function dt(tr){
  return new Date([...tr.children].reverse().map(e=>e.textContent).join(" ")+" 2020");
}

const tbd=$('#table tbody');
tbd.find('tr').sort((a, b)=>dt(a)-dt(b)).appendTo(tbd)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Day</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>March</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```